# Create Table fails with dup error because it does not recognize table was dropped in preceding statement

Tags: sql, hana

Experts...

I have a stored procedure where I am trying to write records to a temporary table.  As a first step I want to unconditionally drop the temporary table (it may not exist), then re-create the table based on a z-table table we have.  Essentially, I'm after an empty table that is a duplicate layout of one particular table for comparisons later.

I tried a simple DROP TABLE but this it's a showstopper if the table doesn't already exist. I found a way, from here, to create another stored procedure that looks in M_TABLES for the temporary table, and drops it if there's a record for it.  I did that.  All good.

The problem is that my SP to drop the table will drop it, but the CREATE TABLE that comes next reacts as if it's still there with SAP DBTech JDBC: [288]: cannot use duplicate table name.  After several tests, I confirmed the drop-table stored-procedure does work as expected.

I thought maybe I should add a 'commit' but I get a compile error that the feature is not supported.

These next two lines are the pertinent code.

```
CALL "SCHEMA1"."Z_PR_DROP_TABLE"('SCHEMA2', 'ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH');

CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA2"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH" AS 
       (select * from "SCHEMA1"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR") WITH NO DATA;
```

**The drop store-procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA1".Z_PR_DROP_TABLE (schema_name VARCHAR2(50), table_name VARCHAR2(50))
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    declare sch varchar2(50);
    declare tab varchar2(50);
    declare cnt int := 0;

    sch := trim(upper(:schema_name));
    tab := trim(upper(:table_name));

    select count(*) into cnt from "PUBLIC"."M_TABLES" where schema_name = :sch and table_name = :tab;

    if (:cnt > 0) then
        exec 'DROP TABLE '||:sch||'.'||:tab;
    end if;

End
```

My work around is to run the drop-table-stored-procedure manually.  I'd prefer to not do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created the stored procedure Z_PR_DROP_TABLE and the two lines worked when ran in the SQL Console

```
    CALL "SYSTEM"."Z_PR_DROP_TABLE"('SYSTEM', 'ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH');

    CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH" AS 
          (select * from "PUBLIC"."DUMMY") WITH NO DATA;
```

The result is

```
    Statement 'CALL "SYSTEM"."Z_PR_DROP_TABLE"('SYSTEM', 'ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH')' 
    successfully executed in 190 ms 259 µs  (server processing time: 14 ms 16 µs) - Rows Affected: 0 


    Statement 'CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH" AS (select * from "PUBLIC"."DUMMY") WITH NO DATA' 
    successfully executed in 91 ms 585 µs  (server processing time: 13 ms 291 µs) - Rows Affected: 0 
    Duration of 2 statements: 281 ms
```

In SQL Console, if the "CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH" AS (select * from "PUBLIC"."DUMMY") WITH NO DATA;" is selected, though there are 2 statements, only selected SQL statement gets executed.

Is this your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your time.    No... In the SQL console?  Works fine.  My issues is that the two statements Will Not run if placed inside a stored procedure and run from there.  I have a SP that executes these two statements back to back.  The Drop-Table SP works perfectly, but the Create-Table fails.   Scenario:  If the temp_table (ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH) exists, the Drop-Table SP will drop it.  However, the Create-Table statement will fail and give the 'cannot use duplicate name' error. === why? -- the temp table (ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH) was just dropped.  Create-Table should create it w/o issue.

Comment: Created a procedure `CREATE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.Z_PR_DROP_AND_CREATE_TABLE LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS BEGIN CALL "SYSTEM"."Z_PR_DROP_TABLE"('SYSTEM', 'ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH'); CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH" AS (select * from "PUBLIC"."DUMMY") WITH NO DATA; END` and it worked! Assuming that the issue is with procedure being in one schema and the table created in a different schema, changed the procedure... `CALL "SYSTEM"."Z_PR_DROP_TABLE"('TEMP1', 'ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH');
CREATE TABLE "TEMP1"."ZTB_CV_SCM_AGGR_FRESH" AS (select * from "PUBLIC"."DUMMY") WITH NO DATA;`. It works!